# how to check if raw_input contains 3 digits?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner and need some help. How can i make sure that the input of user is only 3 digits. I know how to make sure if it is digits but need it to be only 3. This is what i have so far:

```
while not (area_code.isdigit()):
    # do something here
```

I want ".isdigit()" to be 3 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while not len(area_code) == 3:
    # Do stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to explicitly test the length of the string too:

```
while not (area_code.isdigit() and len(area_code) == 3):
```

`str.isdigit()` is only true if there is at least one character and all characters are digits. What remains is a test for the length then.

Comment: Is your logic correct? Should it not  be `while (area_code.isdigit() and len(area_code) == 3)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: no, the `while` loop should continue until a correct `area_code` is found. The OP has `while not area_code.isdigit()`, I merely added the length requirement.

Comment: but how does `while not  area_code.isdigit() and len(area_code) == 3)` loop forever, if it is not defined inside the loop?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: you are forgetting an opening `(` there. The body of the `while` loop is well out of context here, but if `area_code = '123'` in the body would end the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
    inp = raw_input()
    if len(inp) == 3 and inp.isdigit():
        break
```

You need to take the input inside your loop if you want to take multiple input

Using your example:

```
area_code = raw_input()
while len(area_code) != 3 or not area_code.isdigit():
    area_code = raw_input()
```